# How to write technical documentation for Android Project?

Tags: documentation

I have created SRS document, and little Design document. Now, i am struggling to create Technical document which must be used as Reference for new developers when we assign update task to them. What are the things to be in Table of contents?

Comment: Paarthiban, this looks very difficult to answer clearly. Asking "what goes in the TOC" is basically asking us what's important for your developers which is quite broad. Without significantly more information and refactoring, I'm afraid this question isn't answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is ambiguous, so I'll try answering two interpretations.

**I don't know where to start on writing the technical document, but if someone can tell me what belongs in the TOC, I might be able to figure it out from there.**  You have not provided enough detail for us to tell you what belongs in your TOC.  Here are some options:

- Ask someone else on your project
- Ask everyone on your project
- Find a document that describes something similar to your Android project.
- Talk to someone who writes for a living.
- Ask yourself what you think is important for a new developer to know.

If none of that helps, perhaps you should ask someone else to write the technical document.  When you don't know how to do something, it's usually OK to ask for help.

**I think I know what belongs in the technical document but I don't know how to decide what belongs in the TOC.**  This sounds like a pure writing problem that has nothing to do with testing.  Find someone who writes for a living, or if that doesn't work, find someone who *reads a lot*.

Comment: So I got a flag saying this isn't an answer. Part of me wants to agree, but the other part of me says this is about the best it will get because of how broad the question is in its current state.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to try to satisfy my critic.